Looking for nineties album of Zemirot changed to female gender
UPDATE: I was able to finally find it last night: Marcia Falk: Blessings In Song | Fran Avni
As Mike, who referenced Marcia Falk’s book,suggested. Thanks!
https://franavni.bandcamp.com/album/marcia-falk-blessings-in-song
To mbloch: I love Debbie Friedman. Thank you for the welcome!
And finally, thank you for the welcome

Original query:
Many years ago, I had an album of Hebrew blessings in which the female songwriter changed the gender to female (or possibly neutral). Unfortunately, I can’t for the life of me remember the album name or the singer/songwriter.
I can remember one or two songs.
The first was about sacred names. A rough transliteration of the Hebrew would be “nashir l’mishnot kol shem, u l’sham kol neshama”. It’s repeated twice, then sung in English: “let us sing the soul in every name and the same of every soul.”
The other I can only remember in Hebrew, a re-rendering of a bedtime prayer. Please forgive my shaky Hebrew. “Chevlay shayna al aynay utnuma hagaf apie, malod nahshi chodaya al matot hayom.
I’d be thrilled if someone knows of the album and songwriter. Googling is fruitless.
Thank you,
Blythe

Could it be from Debbie Friedman?

Welcome to MiYodeya Blythe and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

"Let us sing the soul in every name and the same of every soul." is by the poet and prolific prayer author and adapter Marsha Falk, copyright 1986. Her books, especially the 1996 Book of Blessings have been widely circulated in liberal and feminist Jewish circles and some poems are even printed as marginalia in siddurim. It would not be surprising if a musician adaptated some of her lines into recorded songs, with her permission of course.  This does not answer your specific question about the singer and album, but may hopefully put you on the right track.

UPDATE: I was able to finally find it last night:
Marcia Falk: Blessings In Song | Fran Avni
As the person who referenced Marcia Falk’s book suggested. Thanks!
https://franavni.bandcamp.com/album/marcia-falk-blessings-in-song
